# NDK APP_CFLAGS can't handle <> characters?

Tags: android-ndk

I am including a procedurally generated file into code used by several libraries, using something like

```
#include MY_CONFIG_FILE_H
```

Then I am attempting to set this value in my `Application.mk` using the following directive

```
APP_CFLAGS += -DMY_CONFIG_FILE_H=<Config/MyFile.h>
```

however, this results in ndk-build not finding the path. It fails right away on the first file it tries to compile

```
"Compile++ thumb : MyLibraryName <= MyFirstFile.cpp
The system cannot find the path specified.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/MyLibraryName/MyFirstFile.o] Error 1
```

Indeed, the file is not there, but it did manage to create the file path. There must be some strange/inconsistent string manipulation going on.

Any ideas? Work arounds? Is this a known issue in `ndk-build.cmd`? For the record I'm on Windows x64 and NDK R9.

Also notice that if I only include `>` and no `<`, I get a different error

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the line to

```
APP_CFLAGS += -DMY_CONFIG_FILE_H="<Config/MyFile.h>"
```

worked. Hope this helps anyone else!